# HTMLCollection seems to be losing every other element when accessing

Tags: javascript, arrays

As you see below in the code, I have a html snippet in string which is then parsed into a document. But when I iterate through it and get the item in the collection, only every other item is accessible. Also some behavior like losing an item in collection also happens and ends up being left with only two items remaining.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hari7190/xpvt214o/878427/

```
var response = "<option value='Bobs Dock'>Bobs Dock</option><option 
value='Johns Dock'>Johns Dock</option><option value='Mikes Dock'>Mikes Dock</option><option value='Jacob Dock'>Jacob Dock</option><option value='Foo Dock'>Foo Dock</option>"

parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString("<select>" + response + "</select>", "text/html");
var options = doc.getElementsByTagName("option");

for(i=0; i<options.length; i++){
    console.log(i, options.length);
    document.getElementById("list").append(options[i]);
}
```

Results of iteration goes like :

```
index - 1 options.length - 3
index - 2 options.length - 2
```

Can anyone explain why this implementation behaves this way?

**Please note: I understand how to achieve the result (like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hari7190/mbugyz24/)), but I am looking for an explanation why the above code behaves this way.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in the `append` function.
You see the, `append` (which is based on the more standard `appendChild`) function adds the node and **detaches it from the current parent**.

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference
>   to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its
>   current position to the new position (there is no requirement to
>   remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other
>   node).

Now, the current parent of these `option` nodes is your `select` node. 
Now, your `options` variable - It might look like it's an array, but its actually an `HTMLCollection`. And, again, from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) :

> An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated
>   when the underlying document is changed.

So in your loop, each time you `append` an element, the appended element is removed from the `select` node, the HTMLCollection `options` sees this and becomes shorter, but since `i` is incremented, you skip over an element.

To see this for yourself you can add a `debugger;` line in your jsfiddle and debug this line by line in the browser.

Comment: beat me by 6 seconds haha -  the only addition I had was that you can fix the issue by cloning and appending  `document.getElementById("list").appendChild(options[i].cloneNode(true))` instead of pulling the node out of the HTMLCollection.